# How to use multiple query.whereEqualTo multiple times with same key

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have a list of objectId ,I want to use these objectId to use these in recycler view. Below is the given code I am using to get my desired results

```
for (int i = 0; i < wishList.size(); i++) {
   q2.whereEqualTo("objectId", wishList.get(i));                  
}
```

But the problem is only last index values  of wishList is applying to my queries, my guess is previous index values are being overriden .

If any other solution please suggest (without using parse relation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can just do

```
q2.whereContainedIn("objectId", wishList)
```

Comment: can wishList be  used with index in whereContainedIn, where wishList is a List

Comment: whereContainedIn can deal with Lists, in this case it should be List<String>. Just try.

Comment: and can it be used for any String key that is excluding objectId?

Comment: Yes, you can use it with the keys you want to filter on